# Sphere-cube collision detection in Opengl?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, collision

I am trying to build a game in Opengl. Before I start making better movement mechanics I want to get collision working. I have cube-cube collision working and I have sphere-sphere collision working, but can't figure out cube-sphere collision. Since I want it in 3d I have the pivot at the center of the objects. Anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT: This is the code I currently have:

```
    bool SphereRectCollision( Sphere& sphere, Rectangle& rect) 
{ 

    //Closest point on collision box
    float cX, cY;

    //Find closest x offset 
    if( sphere.getCenterX() < rect.GetCenterX())//checks if the center of the circle is to the left of the rectangle
        cX = rect.GetCenterX(); 
    else if( sphere.getCenterX() > rect.GetCenterX() + rect.GetWidth()) //checks if the center of the circle is to the right of the rectangle
        cX = rect.GetCenterX() + rect.GetWidth(); 
    else //the circle is inside the rectagle
        cX = sphere.getCenterX(); 

    //Find closest y offset 
    if( sphere.getCenterY() > rect.GetCenterY() + rect.GetHeight() )
        cY = rect.GetCenterY(); 
    else if( sphere.getCenterY() < rect.GetCenterY() - rect.GetHeight() ) 
        cY = rect.GetCenterY() + rect.GetHeight(); 
    else 
        cY = sphere.getCenterY(); 

    //If the closest point is inside the circle 
    if( distanceSquared( sphere.getCenterX(), sphere.getCenterY(), cX, cY ) < sphere.getRadius() * sphere.getRadius() )
    { 
        //This box and the circle have collided 
        return false; 
    }

    //If the shapes have not collided 
    return true; 
}

float distanceSquared( float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2 ) 
{ 
    float deltaX = x2 - x1; 
    float deltaY = y2 - y1; 
    return deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY; 
}
```

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Can you post the code for the collision test so we can see if there's anything wrong with that in particular?

Comment: Are the cubes axis-aligned?

Comment: @user1118321 I have posted my code that I currently have. I know it will need to be changed. I need it to work in 3d space.

Comment: @Nard for now yes, but I want them to work if the objects have been rotated

Comment: @WhyYouNoWork Have you tried the [Separating Axis Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem)?

Comment: @Nard I read the article and am ashamed to say that that went way over my head. Could you explain it?

Comment: @WhyYouNoWork Which part are you not getting?

Comment: @Nard The whole thing was way to technical for me to follow. I'm not even sure how it can be used in collision detection.

Comment: @WhyYouNoWork http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/

Comment: @Nard I was hoping to be able to solve this issue without a plugin. It would be nice to learn it myself so I can know for later. I have I have my code posted now. would you be able to look at it?

Comment: @WhyYouNoWork Where's the Z-axis?!

Comment: In Opengl the positive Z is toward the camera. positive X is to the right and Positive y is up.

http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/images/Graphics3D_RHS.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. I had the right idea, but didn't quite know how to execute it:

```
    bool SphereRectCollision( Sphere& sphere, Rectangle& rect) 
{ 
    float sphereXDistance = abs(sphere.X - rect.X);
    float sphereYDistance = abs(sphere.Y - rect.Y);
    float sphereZDistance = abs(sphere.Z - rect.Z);

    if (sphereXDistance >= (rect.Width + sphere.Radius)) { return false; }
    if (sphereYDistance >= (rect.Height + sphere.Radius)) { return false; }
    if (sphereZDistance >= (rect.Depth + sphere.Radius)) { return false; }

    if (sphereXDistance < (rect.Width)) { return true; } 
    if (sphereYDistance < (rect.Height)) { return true; }
    if (sphereZDistance < (rect.GetDepth)) { return true; }

   float cornerDistance_sq = ((sphereXDistance - rect.Width) * (sphereXDistance - rect.Width)) +
                         ((sphereYDistance - rect.Height) * (sphereYDistance - rect.Height) +
                         ((sphereYDistance - rect.Depth) * (sphereYDistance - rect.Depth)));

    return (cornerDistance_sq < (sphere.Radius * sphere.Radius));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This algorithm doesn't work when a hit happen on an edge, the 2nd set of if conditions triggers but a collision isn't occuring

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).